# Convert Local time to a Specific timezone irrespective of Daylight is ON

Tags: c#-4.0, timezone, dst

I would like to convert local time to PST (Not PDT as its Daylight on currently)
And I would like to have this method generic so that I can use this for any timezone not only for Pacific.

```
public static DateTime ConvertDateToTimezone(DateTime givenDateTime, string timezoneId, bool considerDaylight)
{
    if (!considerDaylight)
    {
        //ToDo need to implement
        // Convert time to "timezoneId" irrespective of Daylight is on or not.
        //    var timezone =
        //       TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()
        //           .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(timezoneId));
        //    TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(givenDateTime, timezoneId);
    }
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(givenDateTime, timezoneId);
}
```

Comment: Basically, you're not after a time zone - PST isn't a time zone - you're just after an offset. Rather than giving an ID for something other than a time zone, can you just pass in the offset you want? Can you give more details about what you're going to do with the result? (It's a very odd requirement.)

Comment: We capture "created date" for all records in DB, client want all those dates to be PST time not server local time. If I convert to timezone, I get PDT time as it is Day Light Saving on currently. I know its a odd requirement, but cant help to explain the client. so instead of hard coded conversions, I wanted to make it more of a generic method that can I can use it for any timezone. Yes I can pass DateTimeOffset.Now if that will give me what I am looking for.

Comment: Why would you want to store in a form which isn't actually anyone's time? If you're not going to store local time, store UTC instead. Anything else just sounds very, very unwieldy to me. If this is just a client requirement, it sounds like you'd be serving your client's interests best by explaining to them why their "requirement" is a bad idea.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I explained to the client, but of no use. they want to force it to PST.

Comment: Then don't use `TimeZoneInfo` at all - just subtract 8 hours from UTC, basically. (It's not clear what form `givenDateTime` is to start with - if you were to use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project, all this would be much clearer.) But I'd strongly recommend having another go at persuading the client. Ask them *why* they have such an odd requirement - they can easily convert from UTC to PST later for display purposes if they really, really want to, of course.

Comment: if I do -8 that will only handle for Pacific right? I cannot handle of all US timezones

Comment: Well you're not really doing a time zone anyway - just a fixed offset. But you'd use -6 for CST and -5 for EST.

Comment: Is there a way I can find these -6 for CST and -5 for EST from TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()?

Comment: I don't know, but it seems odd to need to - these are basically the three common "standard times" of the US. Why do you *want* to use TimeZoneInfo here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to consider the base offset of the time zone, then you could do something like this:

```
public static DateTimeOffset ConvertToTimeZone(DateTimeOffset dto, string timeZoneId, bool considerDaylight)
{
    var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);

    if (considerDaylight)
    {
        // this is the normal behavior
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dto, timeZone);
    }
    else
    {
        // the base offset doesn't include DST adjustment
        return dto.ToOffset(timeZone.BaseUtcOffset);
    }
}
```

However, like Jon mentioned in the question comments, this isn't recommended.  You should probably be storing UTC.  You really should go back and discuss this with your customer.

Also, recognize that sometimes the DST adjustment is used for non-DST purposes, such as when a time zone changes its base offset in the middle of a year.  This happens fairly often outside of the USA.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I accomplished what I need

```
 public static DateTimeOffset ConvertDateToTimezone(DateTimeOffset givenDateTime, string timezoneId, bool considerDaylight)
    {
        if (!considerDaylight)
        {
            var timezone =
               TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()
                   .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(timezoneId));
            var utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(givenDateTime, timezoneId).ToUniversalTime();
            if (timezone != null) return utcTime.AddHours(timezone.BaseUtcOffset.Hours);
        }
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(givenDateTime, timezoneId);
    }
```

Comment: This has a few bugs.  Don't assume all time zone offsets are in whole hours.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting it.